# Using BeyondCompare as the mergetool with git, brings up the diff, not the merge function

Tags: git, mergetool, beyondcompare4

With the mergetool configured for git, I have manufactured a conflict, and then run 'git mergetool', and yet no matter how its configured, it is bringing up a diff, not a merge window.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem was that the Standard edition does not include the text merge functionality.  So if you have this problem, you should either buy the Pro edition, or find a different merge tool.  It would be better if BeyondCompare gave an error in the case where the command line is trying to do a merge, but the license is not for the Pro edition.  Bringing up the diff tool in that case is really not helpful.

Comment: Wow, that (the lack of a warning "this operation isn't in the free version") seems like a horrific bug...

Comment: Actually the standard edition is not free.

Comment: Huh, I think that makes it even worse, if that's possible. :-)